# Como Inserir tag em xml dentro de uma tabela do sql server

Tags: sql, xml, sql-update, sql-insert, sql-server-2012

Estou tentando inserir uma tag XML que se encontra alocada dentro de um campo numa tabela de SQL (SQL SERVER)

atualmente estou tentando assim porem estou sem sucesso:

```
update UserData set tp_ColumnSet.modify('insert <uniqueidentifier2>E2BE0475-2ED2-459D-ACC8-D46A703B605B</uniqueidentifier2> into (/tp_ColumnSet[1])') where  tp_ColumnSet.value('(nvarchar1)[1]', 'nvarchar(300)') = 'Ihara_1571-000_Proposta_Serviço_E-Social '
```

---

Atualmente está assim:

```
<datetime2>2019-05-06T17:53:27</datetime2>    
<datetime3>2019-05-06T17:53:27</datetime3>    
<datetime4>2019-05-06T03:00:00</datetime4>    
<int6>21454</int6>    
<int12>21454</int12>    
<int13>21454</int13>    
<int16>6</int16>    
<int18>4</int18>    
<nvarchar1>Ihara_1571-000_Proposta_Serviço_E-Social </nvarchar1>    
<nvarchar3>Semanal</nvarchar3>    
<nvarchar4>Projeto</nvarchar4>    
<nvarchar7>Aguardando Análise</nvarchar7>    
<nvarchar8>Aguardando Análise</nvarchar8>    
<nvarchar9>Aprovado</nvarchar9>    
<nvarchar10>Muito Baixo</nvarchar10>    
<nvarchar11>Muito Baixo</nvarchar11>    
<nvarchar12>Muito Baixo</nvarchar12>
<nvarchar13>Muito Baixo</nvarchar13>    
<nvarchar14>Muito Baixo</nvarchar14>    
<nvarchar18>Aprovação da Diretoria</nvarchar18>    
<nvarchar19>Diretoria</nvarchar19>    
<nvarchar22>1-612P</nvarchar22>    
<nvarchar25>㮭⩾퀖䟴릚仰ࣔ</nvarchar25>    
<nvarchar26>ڇ쀠앾䭈⻌듯</nvarchar26>    
<nvarchar27>⥧쌪ꞻ䷪㊤뱙還礿</nvarchar27>    
<nvarchar32>/PWA/_layouts/15/wrkstat.aspx?List=3c39c3c7-c966-46f3-93f0-2fd071c47fd3&amp;WorkflowInstanceName=75287446-d222-4a70-92c6-024a7a06e2db</nvarchar32>    
<nvarchar33>Preparar 1</nvarchar33>
```

E precisaria inserir ao final esta tag : `<uniqueidentifier2>E2BE0475-2ED2-459D-ACC8-D46A703B605B</uniqueidentifier2>`

Comment: A coluna é de que tipo? XML ou Varchar?

Comment: @MauroAlmeida a coluna é do tipo **XML**

Comment: Veja a minha resposta e comente lá se precisar de alguma alteração.
Forneci um exemplo prático de como pode fazer.

Comment: @MauroAlmeida veja como respondi lá, pode ser funcional porem neste caso perco a criptografia. :'(

Comment: Sim, pode ter a ver com enconding's diferentes, vou ver

Comment: @MauroAlmeida fico no aguardo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pode fazer assim:**

```
DROP TABLE ##yourTable

CREATE TABLE ##yourTable
(XMLCol XMl);

Insert into ##yourTable 
VALUES(
N'<datetime2>2019-05-06T17:53:27</datetime2>    
<datetime3>2019-05-06T17:53:27</datetime3>    
<datetime4>2019-05-06T03:00:00</datetime4>    
<int6>21454</int6>    
<int12>21454</int12>    
<int13>21454</int13>    
<int16>6</int16>    
<int18>4</int18>    
<nvarchar1>Ihara_1571-000_Proposta_Serviço_E-Social </nvarchar1>    
<nvarchar3>Semanal</nvarchar3>    
<nvarchar4>Projeto</nvarchar4>    
<nvarchar7>Aguardando Análise</nvarchar7>    
<nvarchar8>Aguardando Análise</nvarchar8>    
<nvarchar9>Aprovado</nvarchar9>    
<nvarchar10>Muito Baixo</nvarchar10>    
<nvarchar11>Muito Baixo</nvarchar11>    
<nvarchar12>Muito Baixo</nvarchar12>
<nvarchar13>Muito Baixo</nvarchar13>    
<nvarchar14>Muito Baixo</nvarchar14>    
<nvarchar18>Aprovação da Diretoria</nvarchar18>    
<nvarchar19>Diretoria</nvarchar19>    
<nvarchar22>1-612P</nvarchar22>    
<nvarchar25>㮭⩾퀖䟴릚仰ࣔ</nvarchar25>    
<nvarchar26>ڇ쀠앾䭈⻌듯</nvarchar26>    
<nvarchar27>⥧쌪ꞻ䷪㊤뱙還礿</nvarchar27>    
<nvarchar32>/PWA/_layouts/15/wrkstat.aspx?List=3c39c3c7-c966-46f3-93f0-2fd071c47fd3&amp;WorkflowInstanceName=75287446-d222-4a70-92c6-024a7a06e2db</nvarchar32>    
<nvarchar33>Preparar 1</nvarchar33>')


select XMLCol from ##yourTable

UPDATE ##yourTable SET XMLCol = (
    SELECT CONCAT((
        SELECT CAST(XMLCol as nvarchar(max))FROM ##yourTable), '<uniqueidentifier2>E2BE0475-2ED2-459D-ACC8-D46A703B605B</uniqueidentifier2>'))


select XMLCol from ##yourTable
```

**Ficheiro XML guardado na coluna:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que isto faz é transformar o `XML` num `nvarchar`, concatenar a tag desejada e realizar o update na tabela com o novo valor.

Comment: Quando faço isso estes campos **<nvarchar25>㮭⩾퀖䟴릚仰ࣔ</nvarchar25>    
<nvarchar26>ڇ쀠앾䭈⻌듯</nvarchar26>    
<nvarchar27>⥧쌪ꞻ䷪㊤뱙還礿</nvarchar27> ** as informações ficam assim *<nvarchar25>?????????</nvarchar25>    
<nvarchar26>?????????</nvarchar26>    
<nvarchar27>?????????</nvarchar27>

Comment: Coloquei um N antes da inserção da string inicial e já deu certo.

Comment: Se executar o exemplo no seu **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio** não dá certo?

Comment: muito obrigado sanou meu problema que estou brigando com ele já há uma semana!